# Migrate vmware Esxi 5.0 virtual machines with no hard drive space left

Tags: esxi, vmware-server

I have a VMWare Esxi 5.0 set up on a dedicated server that currently have 0 hard drive space on the host machine (call it Host1) and I am planning to migrate all the VMs to another dedicated server with much larger drive space and has already had VMWare Esxi set up (Call it Host2).

My current strategy is just to copy all the files in datastore1 folder to the new machine via SCP while Host1 has all the VMs shut down. And then hope to see all the VMs shows up in Host2. And once the machine boots up I'll go in and adjust the network configuration to match Host2.

Would this work? Or I have to do more than just that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since you are going to migrate the whole VM's to the new ESxi server, you don't have to copy and paste the VM machine data files since it will take some more time. I will suggest you is to add the datastore directly in to the new exsi server and do storage motion which will reduce the RTO

Comment: Thanks for the answer, problem is Host2 is in a different physical location from Host1 and unless I can somehow remote add the datastore, this might be tough. Also all I have is the vSphere client and not web-based vCenter